# Can't fit all images in the same row using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to get 4 images on the same row in a flexbox container. For some reason I only see three of the four images. The fourth images doesn't show anywhere. I've tried everything I know about flexbox eg. flex-basis, flex-shrink etc. but I can't seem to get it right.
Can someone let me know how I can create this container and fit all four images in it on the same row?
Thanks so much!

```css
.services-images-container {
  display: flex;
}

.services-images-item {
}
```

```html
<section class="services-images-container">
    <img class="services-imagesitem" src="https://picsum.photos/id/300/300" alt="Example image">
    <img class="services-imagesitem" src="https://picsum.photos/id/300/300" alt="Example image">
    <img class="services-imagesitem" src="https://picsum.photos/id/300/300" alt="Example image">
    <img class="services-imagesitem" src="https://picsum.photos/id/300/300" alt="Example image">
  </section>
```

Comment: Your snippet is working fine.

Comment: On your screen it could be that the width of the container is less than the sum of the widths of the images. Flex-box will automatically wrap things if this is the case. If you need it to be all on one row you could look into reduce the width of the images in smaller screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can specify the width of the `img` element to fit the row something like this:

```
.services-images-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.services-images-item {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```